# Stress Testing: 1000 Tranactions at the same Time

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, anchor-lang, candy-machine-v2

I need to know how many transactions the Solana blockchain can handle at a time. Currently, my app can handle around 10-20 transactions at once, but if I send around 50 transactions, let's say 50 NFT mints at the same time then the system crashes. Many goal is to handle 100-1000 transactions at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I need to look into the private RPC nodes such as [Alchemy](https://www.alchemy.com/overviews/rpc-node).

On [Solana Offical Docs](https://docs.solana.com/cluster/rpc-endpoints) it is mentioned that public RPC has the following limitations:

> **Rate Limits#**
>
> Maximum number of requests per 10 seconds per IP: 100
>
> Maximum number of requests per 10 seconds per IP for a single RPC: 40
>
> Maximum concurrent connections per IP: 40
>
> Maximum connection rate per 10 seconds per IP: 40
>
> Maximum amount of data per 30 second: 100 MB